# Cross-Scheme Communication with Silverlight media player

Tags: silverlight, http, ssl, https

We are using a Sliverlight player to play videos on a .Net website.  This player is available on Codeplex at http://slvideoplayer.codeplex.com/releases/view/21749.  This player plays videos from another website served over http (Ex:[http://ThirdpartyWesbite.com/video1.wmv]).  We are currently in the process of implementing SSL on our website and configured our development environment with SSL only to find that the Silverlight video player cannot play the videos anymore.  A little bit of research seemed to indicate that Silverlight does not allow cross-scheme (https -> http) communication.  More specifically Information available on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb820909.aspx seems to indicate Silverlight pretty much prohibits cross-scheme communication.

It is possible that if the third party website serves files over https then my problem would likely go away.  Unfortunately I cannot make them implement SSL on their site.  I just would like to know if there is anybody in the community that faced a similar situation and were able to find any work-around. Any help is greatly appreciated.